# text in cells in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi there I am quite new to swift programming and I am trying to create a to-do-list with my current knowledge but I've sucked here which I dont know how to assign some texts in side the cells of my table .Here is my code

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell : UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle , reuseIdentifier: nil)

        cell.text = taskManeger.tasks[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }
```

I Dont really know what to do with this cell XD Can please some one help me ? :)

Comment: A table view cell has a textLabel property, not text.  Try `cell.textLabel?.text = `.

Comment: oh yeah it works :) thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about UITableviews in detail and take a look at this tutorial. It is pretty simple once you understand how to do it.

https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/

Do take a look at Apple's getting started guide for UITableviews

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html

Hope that helps!